# How to retrieve array in array using GET methos of volley?

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

Im using Rest Countries API to retrieve language data, https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all.. but the languages does't show up because the data was in array.

this is the code that i write to retrieve the data using Method.Get

```
   private void getCountriesList() {

   String url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    if(!response.isEmpty()) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JSONObject json = null;
                        // array of country
                        LanguageModel[] countries = gson.fromJson(response, LanguageModel[].class);
                        // add it to adapter
                        for(LanguageModel country: countries) {
                            mAdapter.addItem(country);
                        }


                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
    );

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(request);
}
```

This is the model. the code was successful when i retrieve country name, but it was failed when i retrieve language data

```
public class CountryModel {

private String languages;

public String getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}

public void setLanguages(String languages) {
    this.languages = languages;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the following code:

```
if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                            Gson gson = new Gson();

                            try {
                                JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject countryObj = mainArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONArray languageArray = countryObj.getJSONArray("languages");
                                    List<LanguageModel> languageModels = gson.fromJson(languageArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<LanguageModel>>() {
                                    }.getType());
                                    // add it to adapter
                                    for (LanguageModel languageModel : languageModels) {
                                        //mAdapter.addItem(country);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // array of country

                        }
```

Let me know if you still get the error.

**Edit:**

**but how to get country name and language at the same time?**

You have to edit your `CountryModel` as following:

```
public class CountryModel {

    @SerializedName("name")
    String countryName;
    @SerializedName("languages")
    ArrayList<LanguageModel> languages;

    public CountryModel() {
    }
}
```

And `LanguageModel` as following:

```
class LanguageModel {


    @SerializedName("iso639_1")
    String iso1;
    @SerializedName("iso639_2")
    String iso2;
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("nativeName")
    String nativeName;

    public LanguageModel() {
    }
}
```

Now the final change in parsing:

```
if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                            Gson gson = new Gson();

                            try {
                                JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                List<CountryModel> countryList = gson.fromJson(mainArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<CountryModel>>() {
                                }.getType());

                                //do something with your country list
                                Log.d("R-Countries", countryList.toString());

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

While this answer works you should see the following link to understand what i did here.

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-introduction/

Comment: but how to get country name and language at the same time?